# Codeigniter user functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, tankauth

im working on a project at the moment that allows users to register and log into there own user area and add/edit/delete note snippets.

Im currently working on the edit class and im wondering how can i make it so that other users cant visit the same url and edit someones note? (all notes are stored in the same table in the database)

schema = id, title, description, snippet, user_id

for example if user1 wants to edit his note at http://domain.com/edit/1 (which is bound to his user_id in the database) how can i stop user2 from visiting that same url and editing his note?

here is the controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mysnippets extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/login/');
    } 

    $this->load->model('dashboard_model');

    $this->data['user_id']  = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $this->data['username']= $this->tank_auth->get_username();  
}

public function index()
{
    $this->data['private_snippets']  = $this->dashboard_model->private_snippets();
    $this->load->view('dashboard/my_snippets', $this->data);    
}

function edit_snippet($snippet_id) {

    $snippet = $this->dashboard_model->get_snippet($snippet_id);

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {       
        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
        {
            $this->dashboard_model->update_snippet($snippet_id, $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Product updated successfully.</p>");                
            redirect(base_url().'mysnippets/edit_snippet/'.$snippet_id);
        }           
    }

    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

    $this->data['snippet'] = $snippet;

    //display the edit product form
    $this->data['title'] = array(
        'name'      => 'title',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('title', $snippet['title']),
    );

    $this->load->view('dashboard/edit_snippet', $this->data);
}
}
```

heres the model:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model {

public function public_snippets()
{
    $this->db->select('id, title, description, author, date_submitted');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('snippets', array('state' => 'public'));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function private_snippets()
{
    $this->db->select('id, title, description, date_submitted');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('snippets', array('user_id' => $this->tank_auth->get_user_id()));
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function add_snippet($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('snippets', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
}

public function get_snippet($snippet_id) {
    $this->db->select('id, title');
    $this->db->where('id', $snippet_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('snippets');

    return $query->row_array();
}

public function update_snippet($snippet_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $snippet_id);
    $this->db->update('snippets', $data);
}




}
```

heres the view:

```
    <?php echo $message;?>

    <?php $snippet_id = $snippet['id']; ?>
    <?php echo form_open("mysnippets/edit_snippet/$snippet_id");?>


    <?php echo form_input($title); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

is there a way i can restrict it so if another user tried to go to that url i can redirect them or show a error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
public function edit_snippet(snippet_id) 
{
    $snippet = $this->dashboard_model->get_snippet($snippet_id); 

    // this depends on what you are using for sessions; 
    // recommend you use db sessions
    if($snippet->user_id != $this->session->userdata('user_id');)
    {
        redirect('/mysnippets');
    } 
    else 
    {
        //allow editing
```

Comment: IM using tank auth for authentication and it handles sessions through storing them in a database, would this work with that? i couldnt get the above working. Thanks for the swift response. Ive updated my post with the full MVC of the function

Comment: Yup, that'll work fine. But in your get_snippet method in your model, you need to also query for user_id. Right now, you're only selecting id and title. Try it with $this->db->select('id, title, user_id');

Comment: still no luck just redirects back to /mysnippets/ even if the user_id is equal to.

Comment: Well that's not quite possible; they're obviously not equal. Try `print_f($snippet)` to make sure the value is there. Also `echo $this->session->userdata('user_id');` to make sure it's set in the session. Make sure the user_id value exists in the db; make sure you set it when you add a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the id you are editing is the same as the session id provided when you have logged in.

it could be something like :

```
if ($snippet_id !=  $this->session->userdata('login_id'))
{
   //redirect to another page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a line to the following function in the model:

```
public function get_snippet($snippet_id) {
    $this->db->select('id, title');
    $this->db->where('id', $snippet_id);
    //users can access only their own snippets 
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get('snippets');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

That prevents them from accessing the information, but I'd do something to prevent them from even being able to try in the first place, i.e. not giving them the choice.